# laravel how bind all classes which implemented specific interface?

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, ioc-container

in laravel 5.4 we can bind a class which known and we use it anywhere after binded but if we wants bind some classes implemented specific interface how we bind dynamically ?

for example:

```
interface x {}

class a implements x {}
class b implements x {}
class c implements x {}
class d implements x {}
class e implements x {}
```

in service provider how can i bind all classes implemented x dynamicaly so in 
 future i will add some class implemeted x. how can i do?

Comment: Check this post https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/container#binding-interfaces-to-implementations , $this->bind('x', 'a') should do the trick, but I don't understand why you need it, cause after every binding a new binded class will be used.

Comment: i will make a notify structure should managed in panel it means when i added a new class implement x it must shown on notify type list in panel and i can use it without does not add anything. ok ?

Comment: i need access all classes implemented x dynamically

Comment: ok what about contextual binding https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/container#contextual-binding ?

Comment: it may help but lets assume added some 10 classes in future, i must add some extra lines but i don't want it. i will use it with dynamicly class names. i don't want add extra lines every added new classes.

Comment: Ok, use tags then, $classes = getYourClassesFromDB(); $this->app->tag($classes, 'x'); and after that use $app->tagged('x') to get all this classes

Comment: i don't want use db . i can not store classes in db . it is so bad way to ioc i think. i want access classes like get_declared_interface and get_declared_class but composer autoload system does not give all class so i can not access

Comment: Ok, understood, then you would have to use scandir($dir); to get list of files, get the name of each file, concatenate it with namespace and use instanceof to check if this class implements needed interface

Comment: My friend told me this way today and you are second who told me so i will try it but i wonder does it take more times to scan all files ?